# how do i calculate the year of birth by it's age and date of today?

Tags: python-3.x

```
Name = input("What is your name?")
Hobby = input("What is your Hobby?")
Color = input("What is your favorite Color?")

print("Ah, so your Name is %s, your Hobby is %s, "
    "and your favorite Color is %s. " % (Name, Hobby, Color))

print("How old are you?")
input("Type your age here:")
```

Hello, I want to calculate the date of birth by their age and the date right now(2018). I need to calculate 2018 - the age of the person. How do I do that? I just cant get it right lol.

Comment: Simply knowing their age can't get you their date of birth. For instance, if a user were to input that they're 25 years old, and you subtract 25 years from 2018, you'll have 1993 as a year but you have no way of knowing which month and day that person was born on.

Comment: @JakeMiller I know that. I just want to know the year of date. I just don't know how to subtract the input with 2018

Comment: `age = int(input("Type your age here:"))` - this will throw an exception if you input non-numbers or floats. then `year = 2018 - age`

Comment: It's worth noting that not everyone who is 25 today was born in 1993, and not everyone who was  born in 1995 is 25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To estimate the birthday-year correctly you need to also ask if the birthday already happened this year:

```
BirthdayDone = input("Did you celebrate your birthday this year?").strip().lower() in [
               "yes","1","true"]

print("How old are you?")
age = int(input("Type your age here:"))  
print(f'Your year of birth is: {2018 - age - (0 if BirthdayDone else 1)}')
```

Then you can give the correct year of birth.

This `input("Did you celebrate your birthday this year?").strip().lower() in ["yes","1","true"]` stripts whitespaces from the answer and if it either `yes`, `1` or `true` will set it to `True` else its `False`. This information is used in the printstatement to decrease the birthday by 1 if it is False to get the correct date of birth.